# What is Coef_.T? Purpose of using T

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pycharm, logistic-regression

Coef_ is used to find coefficients in linear equations in Python. But Coef_, which I could not find the answer to, was put at the end of .T. What is the .T function here?

```
for C, marker in zip([0.001, 1, 100], ['o', '^', 'v']):
 lr_l1 = LogisticRegression(C=C, penalty="l1").fit(X_train, y_train)
 print("Training accuracy of l1 logreg with C={:.3f}: {:.2f}".format(
 C, lr_l1.score(X_train, y_train)))
 print("Test accuracy of l1 logreg with C={:.3f}: {:.2f}".format(
 C, lr_l1.score(X_test, y_test)))
 plt.plot(lr_l1.coef_.T, marker, label="C={:.3f}".format(C))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

".T" method means *Transpose* which switches rows & columns

if you have a matrix **m**:

> [1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 7 8 9]

Then **m.T** would be:

> [1 4 7
> 2 5 8
> 3 6 9]

It looks like its used in this line:

> plt.plot(**lr_l1.coef_.T**,...)

to make sure it plots the coefficients in an expected way. If the model was built from sklearn LogisticRegression, then you can review the docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)
coef_ has shape **(n_classes,n_features)**, so that means 
coef_.T has shape **(n_features,n_classes)**

[Here](https://github.com/delta2echo/StackOverflow_Responses/blob/main/Ploting_Coefficients.ipynb) is a notebook that shows how this works

[image]

Comment: This question has already been answered in the site, do not answer duplicate questions.

Comment: I thought the question warranted a little more explanation only because it was specific to plotting the coef_, so I wanted to illustrate to the OP what was going on. It might be helpful to other users.